# How to reduce array and add related integers together

Tags: lightning-web-components, array, js

i have this array

```js
const input = [
  { StockKeepingUnit: 'SKU-001', Quantity: 3 },
  { StockKeepingUnit: 'SU-002', Quantity: 5 },
  { StockKeepingUnit: 'SU-002', Quantity: 7 },
  { StockKeepingUnit: 'SKU-d7', Quantity: 2 },
  { StockKeepingUnit: 'SKU-d7', Quantity: 4 },
  { StockKeepingUnit: 'sku-899', Quantity: 1 },
  { StockKeepingUnit: 'SU-002', Quantity: 1 },
  { StockKeepingUnit: 'SU-002', Quantity: 2 },
];
```

but I would like for it to be like this

```js
const input = [
  { StockKeepingUnit: 'SKU-001', Quantity: 3 },
  { StockKeepingUnit: 'SU-002', Quantity: 15 },
  { StockKeepingUnit: 'SKU-d7', Quantity: 6 },
  { StockKeepingUnit: 'sku-899', Quantity: 1 },
];
```

So reduce the array but add the quantities together, please, this is driving me crazy. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the best approach would be first doing all the sums, and the formatting as you like

```js
Object.entries(
   input
      .reduce(
         (prev, current) => ({...prev, [current.StockKeepingUnit]: (prev[current.StockKeepingUnit] || 0) + current.Quantity}),
         {}
      )
).map(([StockKeepingUnit, Quantity]) => ({StockKeepingUnit, Quantity}))
```

For your second question, it would be very similar to the first answer, but instead of adding the values, you should add them to lists, and then reduce the items again in order to calculate the average

```js
Object.entries(
   input
      .reduce(
         (prev, current) => ({...prev, [current.StockKeepingUnit]: [...(prev[current.StockKeepingUnit] || []), current.Quantity]}),
         {}
      )
)
    .map(([StockKeepingUnit, Quantity]) => ({StockKeepingUnit, Average: Quantity.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / Quantity.length}))
```

Comment: Amazing thank you. Now say I have this resulted array 
[{"StockKeepingUnit":"SKU-001","Quantity":3},{"StockKeepingUnit":"SU-002","Quantity":15},{"StockKeepingUnit":"SKU-d7","Quantity":6},{"StockKeepingUnit":"sku-899","Quantity":1}]
and i wanted to find the average of quanties. so the array above is the toatl amount and the array below is how many times ordered
 { 'SKU-001': 1, 'SU-002': 4, 'SKU-d7': 2, 'sku-899': 1 }

using the 2 arrays I want to divide total amount by times ordered and then  round it up?

Comment: updated the answer to also calculate the average

Comment: Please can you show me how I would do the same for this array { 'SKU-001':
   { StockKeepingUnit: 'SKU-001',
     Description: true,
     '2022-09-07': 3 },
  'SU-002':
   { StockKeepingUnit: 'SU-002',
     Description: false,
     '2022-09-07': 5,
     '2022-09-20': 7,
  'SKU-d7':
   { StockKeepingUnit: 'SKU-d7',
     Description: false,
     '2022-09-20': 2,
     '2022-09-23': 4 },
   }
so keeping all values the same, but adding an average field for each which will be total order / times ordered. The input could already have an empty average field if that makes it easier